# Altering specific parts of a char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, unsigned-integer

I am trying to set a char array with the first 2 chars equal to 698 in binary, the 3rd and 4th chars a dynamic number under 180 and the rest a predefined set of 150 characters followed by an eof-is there a simple way to alter char arrays so I could, in example, do this:

```
char arr[155];
arr [0-1] = uint_16(698);
arr[2-3] = uint_16(178);
arr[4-154] = (another message);
```

I am new to c++ and am not experienced with these things.

Comment: 1 sub standard way: `chat arr[155] = {uint16_t(698), uint16_t(698),...}`. But your way is technically incorrect.

Comment: so theres no good way of doing this? Maybe creating 3 different char arrays and concatenating them? By the way, my way was pseudo code, not actual c++

Comment: @iammilind I assume the intent is actually { 698/256, 698%256 } rather than both converted to char

Comment: @ M.M They need to both be char arrays of length 2

Comment: @dashiz `698` does not fit in a `char` ... if that's not what you meant then could you please specify exactly what result you are looking for in the array

Comment: How do you represent 698 in binary in only 2 characters??

Comment: @caps the obvious way is 00000010 10111010

Comment: I thought he meant a string representation:`"1010111010"`

Comment: 698 in binary is represented by 16 bits, or 8 bytes, which is 2 characters

Comment: @dashiz do you want 2-186, or 186-2, or something else

Comment: 2-186 would be the correct representation

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not provide language-level mechanisms for array slicing. There are mechanisms you can use to do what you are trying to achieve, though.

You can be clumsy and dangerous and use aliasing (example removed)

But a simpler and cleaner way to do this would be simply to declare a struct:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct Replacement {
    uint16_t first = 698;
    uint16_t second = 178;
    char message[150] = { /*... values ...*/ };
};

int main() {
    Replacement r;
    // use 'r' instead of 'arr'.
}
```

If you want to make absolutely sure there's no padding in the struct

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Replacement {
    uint16_t first = 698;
    uint16_t second = 178;
    char message[150] = { /*... values ...*/ };
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this question that calls for a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: @caps removed it.

Comment: A C-style cast is even worse. What you had before was better. My point is that any solution that involves a cast seems to be looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: @caps I'm going from the fact that he's originally trying to put it into a char array and using the term "message". It makes it look like he's trying to build a byte-buffer for something that takes a `char*` pointer.

Comment: @M.M Aliasing version removed,

Comment: I still need to concatenate first, second, message and '\o' into one char array though: how would I do that?

Comment: @dashiz it's already in a contiguos array of bytes, all you'd have to do is take the address of `r` and cast it to `char*` or `const char*`, e.g. `(char*)&r`.

Comment: That isn't working because I would need to set the 'message' and 'second' values. 

  HelperStru halp;
  halp.second = incheckl;
  strcpy(halp.message,buffer);
  std:: cout << "halp: " << (char *)&halp << ", sizeof(halp): " << sizeof((char*)&halp) << std::end;

results in 'halp: ?, sizeof(halp): 8'

Comment: @dashiz What do you expect the output to be? It may be better to close this question and open another describing the end-goal you're trying to achieve. I'm interpreting it as though you want to create a binary buffer to write as binary data to a socket or file.

Comment: I take it back. Putting a 2-byte number in a `char` array will require some kind of cast.

Answer (score -4):

For 698 and 178, here is a trick.

    `int *a = (int *)arr;
    *a = 678;
    a = (int *)(arr + 2);
    *a = 178;`

It uses overflow to fill char array so the order of assignment must be taken into consideration.

As for another message, if you save it in another char array, use strcpy(better strncpy) to copy it into (arr + 4). Or read the message into (arr + 4) directly.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M could you please talk more about the undefined behaviour? To this question, after 155 bytes are allocated, `*a=678` changes 0-3 and `*a=178` changes 2-5. After copy the message into 4-154, the task is finished.

Comment: @BenLee an `int` lvalue may only be used to modify `int` or `unsigned int` objects. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/1505939)